# Adding text to JTextArea from another class

Tags: java, oop, awtrobot

Basically , I'm trying to make a program that makes the Finch follow the object. I have made two classes : NewOption52 and FollowClass. Class NewOption52 contains a method which determines the properties of the GUI. Class FollowClass contains a main method which calls GUI method from class NewOption52 and it also contains several methods which dictates the Finch's behavior alongside with appending text to JTextArea feed.

When I connect the Finch and run the program , a GUI should appear and inside JTextArea should have text which says ""Please Place An Object in front of Finch And Then Tap Finch to Activate!\n". It didn't happen when I run the program.

Class NewOption52 :

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.*;


public class NewOption52  {



public static   NewOption52 Op = new NewOption52(); 



public static JTextArea feed;
public static JButton halt;
public static JButton exit;
public static JFrame x ;


static protected Finch Grubert = new Finch();

//Method for determining the GUI

static void GUI()
    {

    final JFrame x = new JFrame("Finch Mission : Follow an Object!") ;

 // How the window should be closed
    x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//  Adding a layout manager
    x.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    x.setResizable(false);
    x.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//  Adding components ( significantly a JTextArea being a feedback box ) and adding ActionListeners to each button


    halt = new JButton("Halt!");
    x.add(halt);
    halt.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            feed.append("You have halted the program\n");   
            Grubert.stopWheels();
            Grubert.setLED(0, 0, 0);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(x,"You have halted the program , click OK to go back and please wait for 3 seconds for Finch to start again");
            Grubert.sleep(3000);
            x.repaint();

        }

    });


    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    x.add(exit);
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            Grubert.quit();
            System.exit(0); 
        }

    });                     


    feed = new JTextArea(30,60);
    JScrollPane feedscroll = new JScrollPane(feed);
    x.add(feedscroll);


// Arrange components neatly inside the window
    x.pack();

// Making the window visible once Window is called
    x.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Class FollowClass :

```
    import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class FollowClass {

private static Finch Grubert = null;


private static int TapCount = 0;

public static JTextArea feed;
public static JButton halt;
public static JButton exit;
public static JFrame x ;




//public Finch Grubert = new Finch();



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //refers to first method to start program
    NewOption52.GUI();
}


public static void Finch()
{
    Grubert = new Finch();
    ProgramFollow();


}


private static void ProgramFollow() {

    // Loop to wait for Finch to be tapped and an obstacle detected in front of the Finch   
    boolean StartProgram = true;
    NewOption52.feed.append("Please Place An Object in front of Finch And Then Tap Finch to Activate!\n");  

    while (StartProgram)
    {   

    // Conditional statement for same thing as mentioned above  

    if (Grubert.isTapped()==true && Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
    {   
    feed.append("Finch is activated! Object is detected!\n");   
    Grubert.setLED(red,0,0);
    Grubert.setWheelVelocities(leftVelocity, rightVelocity);


    // Triggers RunAgain to true so the program doesnt stop in one run in order for Finch to move continuosuly

    boolean RunAgain=true;


    while(RunAgain)
    {

    // Calling Movement method  for Finch movements

    Movement();

    // Inside while RunAgain loop , there is the incremental function called TapCount to determine how many times the Finch has been tapped

    if (Grubert.isTapped()==true)
    {

    TapCount++;
    feed.append("You have tapped the Finch. If TapCount = 3 , the program will terminate only if the object is not moving\n");
    feed.append("Number of Taps:" + TapCount + "\n");



    if (TapCount==3 && Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==false)
    {   


    Grubert.stopWheels();
    Grubert.setLED(0, 0, 0);    
    TapCount = 1;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(x,"You have tapped the Finch twice when the object is moving. Please click OK and wait for 3 seconds. Make sure the object is not moving in order for program to terminate when you have tapped it twice");
    Grubert.sleep(3000);

    }

    if (TapCount==3 && Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
    {
    Grubert.quit();
    System.exit(0);


    }
    }

    }
    }
    }
    }



    // Method for Finch movements

    private static void Movement()

    {

    if (Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==false)

    {

    // send message to the feedback box ("Object is Detected! Following it now!");
    feed.append("Following the Object now!\n");

    StraightMovement();

    }

    else if (Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==false)

    {

    feed.append("Object detected on the left side\n");  

    LeftMovement();

    }

    else if (Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==true)

    {

    feed.append("Object detected on the right side\n");

    RightMovement();

    }

    else if (Grubert.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && Grubert.isObstacleRightSide()==true)

    {


    StopMovement();

    }

    }


    // Area of variables declaration for easy value modifications

    static int Buzz = 500;
    static int BuzzDuration = 10;


    static int red = 255;
    static int green = 255;

    static int leftVelocity = 100;
    static int rightVelocity = 100;

    static int leftTurnV = -50;
    static int rightTurnV = -50;;


    // Area of variables declaration for easy value modifications


    private static void StraightMovement()

    {

    Grubert.setLED(0, green, 0);

    Grubert.setWheelVelocities(leftVelocity, rightVelocity);

    Grubert.buzz(Buzz, BuzzDuration);

    }

    private static void LeftMovement()

    {

    Grubert.setLED(0, green, 0);

    Grubert.setWheelVelocities(leftTurnV, rightVelocity);

    Grubert.buzz(Buzz, BuzzDuration);

    }

    private static void RightMovement()

    {

    Grubert.setLED(0, green, 0);

    Grubert.setWheelVelocities(leftVelocity, rightTurnV);

    Grubert.buzz(Buzz, BuzzDuration);

    }

    private static void StopMovement()

    {

    Grubert.setLED(red, 0 , 0);

    Grubert.stopWheels();


    }

}
```